# Display Different report based on a parameter value in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

We have an `SSRS Report` which uses `user authentication`. I have requirement as below

> If an unauthorized user login to see SSRS Report, He/She should only
>   see the "You are not authorized error" message. He/She should not have
>   any visibility to report parameters or any other report elements.

Below is what I have done.

I Created a new `parameter` in the report to store the `user-access` value. If the value is 'Y'  `report` will be shown. Else hide the report and show only the `tablix` with the error message. However, `parameter panel` is visible in both cases. I need the parameter panel to be `hidden` in the Report when the error message displays.

Is it possible to call a `sub-report` and show it with `hidden parameters` if the user-access parameter value set as "N" instead of actual report?

Thanks
baiju

Comment: Why don't you set permissions at the SSRS site page level? Let AD security and SSRS determine if they have access to the reports or not.

Comment: this ssrs report is rendering from a web application. So the authentication taken care at application level

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to call a sub-report and show it with hidden parameters
>   if the user-access parameter value set as "N" instead of actual
>   report?

Yes, sort of.   What you would actually do is have both reports be sub-reports.  Your main report would just be a wrapper for the sub-reports, and the parameter would determine which sub-report you show.

Comment: thanks. But when the authorized user login, I need to show the report with parameters. If we call this sub-report, we will see its parameters or the main  report parameters?

Comment: You will see the main report parameters, so you will need to give the all the parameters that you need to the main report, and then pass their values to the sub reports.